# Error while using a loss from the GlobalObjectives library

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

The global objectives is a library in the research module of Tensorflow that allows for direct cost-sensitive training, which is invaluable in some domains  where weighted loss penalties for the most part do a poor job in acquiring the desired behaviour.

I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend and I've run into some issues trying to use some of the global_objective losses, and I was wondering if anyone else was using them and came up with similar issues. Theoretically, Keras can use as a loss function any function that takes logits and labels as inputs and returns a loss metric. This is the traceback:

```
File "keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 404, in weighted
  score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)

File "GlobalObjTest.py", line 39, in tpratfpr
  loos = loss_layers.true_positive_rate_at_false_positive_rate_loss(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred, target_rate=0.001)

File "tensorflow/models/research/global_objectives/loss_layers.py", line 687, in true_positive_rate_at_false_positive_rate_loss
  label_priors, labels, weights, variables_collections)

File "tensorflow/models/research/global_objectives/loss_layers.py", line 875, in maybe_create_label_priors
  variables_collections=variables_collections)

File "tensorflow/models/research/global_objectives/util.py", line 274, in build_label_priors
  [positive_pseudocount] * num_labels, dtype=dtype),

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType'
```

The issue is located at the function build_label_priors where the dtype and num_labels of the provided 'labels' argument are 'non-int' and 'NoneType' respectively.

```
 dtype = labels.dtype.base_dtype
 num_labels = get_num_labels(labels)
```

The above take place after the model.compile command and before the model.fit command. Does the error have something to do with the lazy execution? Because it attempts to calculate the size and dtype of the labels provided (that are not available at compile time) and not from the num_classes argument (that it is). What am I missing here?

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem (i.e. trying to use the loss function from Global Objectives as part of Keras), and keep getting the error you describe. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Nope, I did not. If I at some point revisit it and find an answer, I will post it here. In the meanwhile, let's see if others get the same problem.